# Why doesn't Python evaluate constant number arithmetic before compiling to bytecode?

Tags: python, bytecode

In the following code, why doesn't Python compile `f2` to the same bytecode as `f1`?

Is there a reason not to?

```
>>> def f1(x):
    x*100

>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              7 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             11 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def f2(x):
        x*10*10

>>> dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              7 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             10 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             11 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is because `x` could have a `__mul__` method with side-effects.  `x * 10 * 10` calls `__mul__` twice, while `x * 100` only calls it once:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__ (self):
...             self.val = 5
...     def __mul__ (self, other):
...             print "Called __mul__: %s" % (other)
...             self.val = self.val * other
...             return self
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a * 10 * 10
Called __mul__: 10
Called __mul__: 10
<__main__.Foo object at 0x1017c4990>
```

Automatically folding the constants and only calling `__mul__` once could change behavior.

You can get the optimization you want by reordering the operation such that the constants are multiplied first (or, as mentioned in the comments, using parentheses to group them such that they are merely operated on together, regardless of position), thus making explicit your desire for the folding to happen:

```
>>> def f1(x):
...     return 10 * 10 * x
... 
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Note that even is nothing is passed to the method, the result of `dis` is still the same i.e. if the contents of the method are: `x = 9; y = x * 10 * 10;`, the result is still the same viz. loading const twice. It seems that Python doesn't do whole method optimization?

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: The compiler still can't really know what `x` is, so it has to play it safe.  Python's versatile introspection and dynamic runtime modification capabilities make it possible to change the type of `x` inside the function locals.

Comment: It could have a `__mul__` method that isn't associative, or that doesn't accept an `int` on the RHS, for that matter.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Sure - I would classify the first under "has side-effects", and the second is irrelevant to whether you can optimize RHS constant multiplication - if it were grammatically allowed you could still do that in the compiler and properly fail in the `__mul__` method

Comment: I wanted to joke that x * 10 * 10 == x * 101 for large values of 10. This answer shows that the joke has some value as it illustrates that, for all that we know, x.__mul__ may implement interval arithmetic. (I have rewritten this comment to eliminate the word "literally" as a concession to Blindy.)

Comment: @minopret: x * 10 * 10 could equal x * 560374, for all we know…you can do whatever you want in `__mul__`.. :-)

Answer (score 17):

Python evaluates expressions from [left to right](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/evalorder.html). For `f2()`, this means it will first evaluate `x*10` and then multiply the result by 10. Try:

Try:

```
def f2(x):
    10*10*x
```

This should be optimized.

Comment: Cool!  also confirmed on cpython 2.6.6